# How can I use Sencha Touch 2 in a Rails 3 app?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Sencha Touch 2 is a framework for writing web or native applications targeted towards mobile devices. See: http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/

I can make apps quickly that work out of the box under a standard LAMP install, but things quickly fall apart when I try and use Sencha with Rails in an active, existing project. Additionally, I can't have it sit in the root directory like most tutorials would like you to do.

I've configured the code enough to allow the app to sit at m.example.com/ and have its resources exposed via example.com/sencha/app (app.json), example.com/sencha/js (sencha-touch.js), and example.com/sencha/css (sencha-touch.css).

I can load my app in my browser by including the bootstrap js in a Rails view, but I'm merely greeted with the blue screen and 3 flashing dots. There are no errors in the Chrome console, and nothing else happens.

Tutorials on the web are scarce, and I've worked through most of them on separate occasions, but they're all for Rails 2 that I've seen. I tried

- http://mikehoitomt.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/sencha-touch-application-with-ruby-on-rails-part-1/ and
- http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2011/12/14/sencha-touch-mvc-with-rails/

But I've also seen the question [Sencha Touch Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301957/sencha-touch-rails-3-1), so I know *someone* has made it work, somewhere.

Where can I find help on making Sencha Touch 2 work in existing Rails 3 apps?

Answer (score 0):

Try it under Safari or check the Chrome console for errors.  I think Chrome gives an error in the basic setup related to security:

[Phonegap + Sencha + Android : ajax request with a basic access authentication failled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068557/phonegap-sencha-android-ajax-request-with-a-basic-access-authentication-fa)

In this question, I use an index.html that points to a Sencha Touch 2 CDN.  This is all you need to set up ST2.

[Creating a 2x2 Button Grid with Centered Buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126628/creating-a-2x2-button-grid-with-centered-buttons)